# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: magento2, database

I'm getting this message sporadically all of a sudden and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
    [2017-04-07 20:09:32] main.CRITICAL: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] 
Connection refused in /httpdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128
```

Here is my mysql configuration in magento

```
array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'database',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
```

Comment: you either have selinux or change localhost to 127.0.0.1. or check where is your mysql listening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming your file `app/etc/env.php`, so run the install process again (don't worry all your data will keep saved), then run these commands below.

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"
composer update -vv && composer install &&
chmod -R 777 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ vendor/magento var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
mage cache:clean &
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy ; mage setup:static-content:deploy -f;
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 777 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Answer (score 3):

you must fix env.php file like this

```
'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => '127.0.0.1:8889',
                'dbname' => 'magentoc',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => 'root',
                'active' => '1',
                'driver_options' => [

                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
```