# main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: magento2

I am using magento 2.3.4 version and i am keep getting this error Multiple times

```
main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused {"report_id":"d953b23017cc156845a623c7225f2e281cf201d080f960026cb40a49fcdaf44b","exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused at /var/www/html/vectorx/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:144, PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused at /var/www/html/vectorx/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128)"} []
```

I tried searching and I found renaming localhost to 127.0.0.1 
but this is not working for me how can I solver this error

Comment: you change `app/etc/env.php` file ???

Comment: i just change localhost to 127.0.0.1 no other changes made

Comment: Yes, but same changes in env.php file???

Comment: yes i have only made changes in env.php file

Comment: try to `core_config_data` table

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/168217/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `host` from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` in `app/etc/env.php`